# Sidebar missing from Cases Record Detail page

Tags: case, sidebar

None of the sidebar items (Create New, Recent Items) show up. There is essentially no sidebar on the Case Record Detail page.

I have "Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages" checked in Setup>Customize>User Interface. I also have Enable Collapsible Sidebar turned off.

I checked the css and:

```
.sidebarCollapsed #sidebarDiv {
    display: none
}
```

is the only thing that would hide it, but I have collapsible sidebars turned off.

It appears that the whole sidebar is just missing on the Case Details View page. Any ideas?

Force.com Quick Access Menu is missing as well.

EDIT - Someone brought up that it might be something related to Feed based Case Layout pages introduced in Spring '14. Here are the page layouts I have available - http://screencast.com/t/rNRX0ChD

Found this 'Hide Sidebar' option on the Feed Layout Editor. Already was unchecked - http://screencast.com/t/Pubeg1hiT

Comment: Did you check your home page components to see if there is a component that contains this CSS?

Comment: Great idea to check. Just did.  We have 4 custom Home Page Components. None of them custom html or css even contain 'sidebar'.  Messages and Alerts can contain css but we don't have any custom css there.

Comment: are u sure the page that is loading does not have a c.naXX./apex/, inshort is it a custom or a standard page? are you a sys admin or a user in the sandbox/prod org you are looking into.

Comment: No apex in the url, it is a standard page. I am a sys admin. Here is a screenshot. http://screencast.com/t/pz0fHnk5th8

Comment: Made sure that the sidebar wasn't just hidden. The Salesforce create new Record button has an id `createNewButton`. This does not exist on the Case Record Detail page. So it is not hidden, doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when trying to set up Case Feed in the last few days.

One item that confused me was that after making changes in the "Custom Console Components" I went back into the Console view and refreshed my browser to see if changes had taken effect - nothing seemed to have happened. HOWEVER - I was observing this on a case that was already open in the console view. Closing the Case and reopening it allowed me to see that the changes HAD taken effect. Simple - but annoying.

Another thing to look out for is to check that you are looking at the right Page Layout. Obvious I know, but even as Sys Admin it might be that you have not enabled the Page Layout for your profile.

I made a large number of configuration changes in my attempt to work out what was going wrong, so I may have done something else to get it working - including removing all the components showing in the Left and Right pane (in the Other Feed View>Other Tools & Components). But this may have been inconsequential - and the primary issue of not closing and reopening the case being the thing that was confusing me.

Perhaps my frustrating experience will help some other poor unfortunate soul who is struggling with this!

Answer (score 2):

On the feed view of the case feed page layout, we have a checkbox to hide the sidebar.  You need to uncheck this to make the Sidebar visible on the case detail page.
Hope, this helps you.

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunately, we already have the 'Hide Sidebar' checkbox unchecked. - http://screencast.com/t/Pubeg1hiT

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if case feeds are enabled for your org?

Setup --> cases --> support settings --> Enable Case Feed Actions

> Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items
>
> Checked
>
> Use this setting to
> turn on Case Feed-specific actions and feed items. When you select
> this option, existing cases are upgraded to the Case Feed user
> interface.

Comment: Yes, Case Feed Actions were/are enabled. http://screencast.com/t/YkBH1nevBO. Still no sidebar?